# Issue in angular js routeProvider

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, route-provider

I have a problem in angular js routeProvider. If i am clicking register or login link then its not going to the next page just shows url like this. `http://localhost:3000/#/register` or `http://localhost:3000/#/login`
Following is my code. thanks in advance
// I gave ngRoute,ngResource, services for intializing myapp but no benefit

script.js

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {


    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl : '/template/login.html',
        controller : loginController
    }).when('/register', {
        templateUrl : '/template/register.html',
        controller : registerController
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
}] );
```

login.js

```
function loginController($scope){
}
```

register.js

```
function registerController($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        if (!($scope.cnfrmPasswd == $scope.passwd)) {

        } else {
            $.get("/register/"+$scope.name+"/"+$scope.username+"/"+$scope.passwd, function(data) {

            });
        }
    };
}
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head >
<script src="js/angular/angular-1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<script src="js/register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#/register">register</a>
<a href="#/login">login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

// I tried by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>` `<script src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>`

Comment: are there any errors in browsers console? If you use angular 1.2.0 you need to include angular-route.min.js too.

Comment: @ bekite no error in console, i tried with angular-route.min.js also

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ngView inside your index.html:

```
<body>
  <a href="#/register">register</a>
  <a href="#/login">login</a>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

Define your controllers with `app.controller('LoginCtrl', ...)` and reference them with their name as string:

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
  templateUrl : '/template/login.html',
  controller : 'LoginCtrl'
})
```

Comment: I added  <ng-view></ng-view> but not working and it is working if im runing it with node js. it is not working if im just open that file in browser. itz only front end code then why this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ng-view inside your body tag and you need to define 'ngRoute' inside your module.

body tag of your index.html

```
<body>

<a href="#/register">register</a>
<a href="#/login">login</a>
<div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view"></div>
</body>
```

Your myapp variable after added **'ngRoute'**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
```

lets see it will work fine.